# Is the molecule in the attached image technically an amino acid?

Tags: terminology, amino-acids

Is the molecule pictured below an amino acid? Not necessarily one of the common (natural) amino acids.

[image: Is the molecule pictured an amino acid?]

Comment: Hello Mike! Welcome to StackExchange! Your molecule isn't an amino acid, since amino acids by definition, must have an **amino** and **carboxylic acid** group.

Comment: Since you're new to this site, have a look at the FAQ and learn how to use this site better. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: It is a sort of peptide as it has the C-CONH-C grouping.

Answer (score 5):

No it is not, as there is no carboxylic acid functionality present. An amino acid is defined in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid) as follows:

> Amino acids are organic compounds containing amine ($\ce{-NH2}$) and carboxyl ($\ce{-COOH}$) functional groups, along with a side chain (R group) specific to each amino acid.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not.

1. However, the starting structure for it is [gamma-Aminobutyric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-Aminobutyric_acid), or GABA:

[image]

2. Rather than the carboxylic acid ($\ce{-COOH}$) at one end, there is a [peptide bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peptide_bond) ($-\ce{C(=O)NH}-$).
3. Attached to the peptide bond is the most unnatural part, the $\ce{-CH2C(CH3)=CH2}$ organic tail.